# Can't get multi-field search to work

Tags: php, mysql

I have two pages, one for my search and one for search results. So far only my search bar with keywords will search. I can't get my finalist checkbox to work. Any help is appreciated-new at all of this. Thanks!

Search page:

```
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/session.php");?>
<?php require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/db_connection.php");?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/functions.php");?>

<?php include("../includes/header-home.php"); ?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col=md-12">
    <p><strong>Search:</strong></p>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="search_results.php">
    <p><input name="search" type="text" size="40" maxlength="50"/> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" /></p>
<p><strong>Type:</strong></p>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="search_results.php">
<p><input type="checkbox" name="keywords[]" value="1"> Finalist <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" /></p>

    </div></div>
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/footer.php");?>
```

Search Results page:

```
?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/session.php");?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/db_connection.php");?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/functions.php");?>

<?php
if (!isset ($_POST['search'])) {
    header("Location:admin.php");
}
$search_sqli="SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE first_name LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' OR last_name LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' OR first_name2 LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' OR last_name2 LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' OR last_name2 LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' OR city LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' OR agency LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' OR subcomponent LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' OR team_name LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' OR achievement LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' OR profile LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%'";
$search_query=mysqli_query($connection, $search_sqli);
if (mysqli_num_rows($search_query) !=0)  {
$search_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query);
}

else{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE finalist = '1'";
   $search_query=mysqli_query($connection, $search_sqli);
if (mysqli_num_rows($search_query) !=0)  {
$search_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query);
}
}
?>



<?php include("../includes/header-home.php"); ?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col=md-12">
     <p>Search:</p>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="search_results.php">
    <input name="search" type="text" size="40" maxlength="50"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />

    </form>
   <br />
    <p><strong>Search Results:</strong></p>
  <?php if (mysqli_num_rows($search_query) !=0) {
     do  {
         ?>
    <p><ul>
    <li><a href="view_profile.php?profile=<?php echo urlencode($search_rs["id"]); ?>"><?php echo $search_rs['first_name']; ?> <?php echo $search_rs['last_name']; ?> <?php echo $search_rs['first_name2']; ?> <?php echo $search_rs['last_name2']; ?></a></li></ul></p>     

<?php } while ($search_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query));

  } else {
      echo "No results found";
  }
  ?>

  <p> <a class="btn btn-default" href="search.php" role="button">Back to search</a></p>
    </div></div>

<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/footer.php");?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make one form to hold all input tags and only one submit input:

```
<p><strong>Search:</strong></p>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="search_results.php">
    <p><input name="search" type="text" size="40" maxlength="50"/></p>
    <p><strong>Type:</strong></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="keywords[]" value="1"> Finalist</p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" /></p>
</form>
```

If you create different forms, only the data from the one that holds the submit button you use is sent with the request.

After that, you also need to combine the two queries into one, something like this:

```
$search_sqli="SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE 
    (first_name LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR last_name LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR first_name2 LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR last_name2 LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR last_name2 LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR city LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR agency LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR subcomponent LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR team_name LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR achievement LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR profile LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%')" 
    . (isset($_POST['keywords']) && in_array('1', $_POST['keywords']) ? " AND finalist='1'" : "");
```

This adds `AND finalist='1'` to the end of the query if the checkbox was marked.

Comment: Thank you! But now, when I just check the "Finalist" box, it pulls all of my records, not just the ones who are finalists...any ideas? Much appreciated.

Comment: @surfingpig right, you need to change the query as well. I updated my answer.

Comment: I get this error now: Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /search_results.php on line 21

Comment: @surfingpig you're right, I modified the code, that should resolve it.

Comment: Hm. This makes the keyword search work again, but when I select just the checkbox, the query still pulls all of my records and not just the finalists. Additionally, when I search for a name and check the finalist box, the name will still populate even if that person is NOT a finalist. Sorry for all of the trouble. I appreciate you helping me.

Comment: @surfingpig that's odd. You did copy the brackets I added to the SQL query? Perhaps you could make a pastebin with your current code, then I can check with the most recent version.

Comment: @surfingpig that's exactly what I mean, thanks! I'm sorry, I made a typo. I had `$_POST['finalist']` which should've been `$_POST['keywords']`. I updated the code in my answer.

Comment: Hooray!! That works. Thank you SO MUCH! So if I wanted to add one more check box to the form for "Medalist" would I repeat the same line basically?

Comment: @surfingpig happy to help :) Yes, essentially you add a new input with the same name `keywords[]` but a different value, say, `2`. Then in the query you need to do the `in_array()` on `'2'` instead of `'1'`. Does that make sense or shall I update my answer with an example?

Comment: That does make sense, but if I am pulling from mySQL where medalist is tinyINT field with 1 being true, can I still give it the value of 2?

Comment: Wait, figured it out! Thank you again! You're the best!

Comment: sorry to be a pain, but can I ask you one more question? I am now trying to add radio buttons to my search form for searching by categories. I have the categories set up as integer values in mySQL DB. How would I set that up in my code? I assume the same method as the checkboxes will not work...I have about 10 categories...

Comment: @surfingpig it would be better to ask that as a separate question. If I'd add it to the answer here it would be confusing for future visitors coming from search engines. Thanks!